# WPF ControlTemplate Content Reset, when the control re-add to visual tree

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, null, reset

i create some custom control, and i set the control template; 
when the windows loaded, i **re-add the control**, would occur **template reset, or template is null**...

Summary questions:

- simpleTextBox.Text **auto reset to "Layer1",** when simpleTextBox **re-add
  into canvas**
- if **recover** MainWindow.cs code snippet : //**simpleTextBox.Reload();** //
  recover this comment, it would **throw exception : textBox is null!**
- i want re-add simpleTextBox in canvas, the Text Property is **src Text;**
- and i want re-add simpleTextBox in canvas, the
  **SimpleTextBox.GetTextBox** is not null;

i don't want Text resetted to "Layer1"
i just wish the Text is src-value after click it...and Template can FindName("TextBox") obj is not null

code snippet：

custom-control .cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;

namespace MyWpfTest.BaseControl
{
    public class SimpleTextBox : Control
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty;

        static SimpleTextBox()
        {
            TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Text",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(SimpleTextBox),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextPropertyChanged))
                );
        }

        private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = d as SimpleTextBox;
            if (control == null) return;
            var textBox = GetTextBox(control);
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                textBox.Text = control.Text;
            }
        }

        public static TextBox GetTextBox(SimpleTextBox control)
        {
            if (control.Template == null) return null; // also somtimes control.Template is null
            return control.Template.FindName("TextBox", control) as TextBox;
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public SimpleTextBox()
        {
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(SimpleTextBox_Loaded);
        }

        void SimpleTextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Reload();
        }

        public void Reload()
        {
            var textBox = GetTextBox(this);
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                textBox.Text = this.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("textBox is null!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

control stenciles files:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:baseControl="clr-namespace:MyWpfTest.BaseControl"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type baseControl:SimpleTextBox}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type baseControl:SimpleTextBox}">
        <Grid>
          <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Text="Layer1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" Focusable="False"/>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MainWindow.xmal:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="232" Width="723"
        xmlns:layerns="clr-namespace:MyWpfTest.BaseControl"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="templates/Stenclis.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Canvas x:Name="c1">
        <layerns:SimpleTextBox x:Name="layerName1" Background="Green" Canvas.Left="61" Canvas.Top="23" Height="39" Text="This is Simple TextBox1, click me to Remove from canvas, and re-add into canvas immediately" Width="Auto" />
        <layerns:SimpleTextBox x:Name="layerName2" Background="Green" Canvas.Left="61" Canvas.Top="68" Height="39" Text="This is Simple TextBox2 is not adding PreviewMouseDown event" Width="Auto" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

MainWindow .cs code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using MyWpfTest.BaseControl;

namespace MyWpfTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml interacted logical
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.layerName1.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(l1_PreviewMouseDown);

            // it's OK! why? action l1_PreviewMouseDown(this.layerName1, null) will occur : simpletText.Text reset to Template's Text("Layer1")
            c1.Children.Remove(this.layerName1);
            c1.Children.Add(this.layerName1);
        }

        void l1_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var simpleTextBox = sender as SimpleTextBox;

            c1.Children.Remove(simpleTextBox); // just re-add it
            //c1.Children.Insert(0, l);
            c1.Children.Add(simpleTextBox);

            //simpleTextBox.Reload(); // recover this comment, it would throw exception : textBox is null! 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: simpleTextBox.Text auto reset to "Layer1", when simpleTextBox re-add into canvas,

Comment: Is text being resetted or is it not? Do you wish it to be resetted?

Comment: i wish the Text is src-value after click it...and Template can FindName("TextBox") obj is not null

Comment: I understand now. I think I do. Let me post you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now that your main issue is in this method:

```
    void l1_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var simpleTextBox = sender as SimpleTextBox;

        c1.Children.Remove(simpleTextBox); // just re-add it
        //c1.Children.Insert(0, l);
        c1.Children.Add(simpleTextBox);

        //simpleTextBox.Reload(); // recover this comment, it would throw exception : textBox is null! 
    }
```

You wish to call the simpleTextBox.Reload() but TextBox is always null.

That is happening because TextBox hasnt become part of VisualTree right after Add(...).

In order to make it work you should try dispatching the action.

Like this:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => simpleTextBox.Reload()));
```

I am not sure if I spelled the code correctly though compiler will scream if not anyways.

Try it out and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: but i don't know why it can workd...i will set it answered...do u have any information about this...that will be better!!!

Comment: It works because when you add something to Canvas it will not be added automatically but instead it will be pushed on a dispatcher frame. When next cpu cycle starts the frame will be executed. That is how wpf works. WPF is not WinForms.

Comment: Any action that changes visualtree in wpf is async